# Detect click on WKInterfaceLabel or WKInterfaceGroup in WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I'm displaying circular progress bar with a label like this:

[image]

and I achieve this by creating `WKInterfaceGroup` and set its image to the animated images, then I put centred `WKInterfaceLabel`.
Now I want to present another view controller when user clicks on the label or on the circular progress bar. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `WKInterfaceButton` can have one of two content types: a label or a group. This means you can put your existing group inside a button and have the button trigger the desired action. You can change the button's content type in your storyboard.

I'd suggest taking a look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/) for `WKInterfaceButton`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!. Works fine by using WKInterfaceButton in group mode